# Area of rectangle?

Tags: geometry

If the sides of a rectangle are $a+b$ and $\frac{1}{2}(a+b)$ does the area equal to $\frac{1}{2}a^2+\frac{1}{2}b^2$ or did I make  a mistake somewhere?

Comment: $(a+b)(a+b)$ is not equivalent to $a^2+b^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $\frac{1}{2}(a+b)^2=\frac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{2}\neq\frac{1}{2}a^2+\frac{1}{2}b^2$.

Comment: Aw, I get it now. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=2$ and $b=4$.

The sides are $6$ and $3$, making the area $18$.

But $\dfrac{2^2+4^2}2=10$ !

Answer (score 0):

$(a+b)^2$ is not $a^2+b^2 \,! $ ; you should actually get $ \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2} + ab.$

Answer (score 0):

The two sides are a+b and 1/2(a+b)
Area = a+b x 1/2(a+b)
     = a(a/2 +b/2) x b(a/2 + b/2)
     = (a^2 + 2ba + b^2)/2
     = (a+b)^2/2  {ANS}